# Is there a way to fix the "Function expressions can't be named" error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter-web

I watched a video tutorial for learning flutter and I encountered an error using the map method, can you help me fix it?

This is the link of the video I watched and followed along : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0uinJvhNxI&t=18425s

This is the code :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import './question.dart';
import './answer.dart';
class Quiz extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Map<String, Object>> questions;
  final int questionIndex;
  final Function answerQuestion;

  Quiz(\{required this.questions, required this.answerQuestion,required this.questionIndex});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
       Question(
                questions[questionIndex]['questionText'] as String,
                /* answerQuestion(Named function) is a pointer that is passed as a value to onPressed but not the result of the function name ;*/ // onpressed attribute requires a function
              ),
              ...(questions[questionIndex]['answers'] as List<Map<String,Object>>).map(answer){      //Creating a list of widgets
                return Answer(() => answerQuestion(answer['score']),answer['text']); // Return a widget
              }.toList() // Based on the old List, it creates a new List

            ],
          );
  } 
}
```

Comment: please describe what problem you faced. If possible give error logs. rather than giving YouTube tutorials.

Comment: I’m getting an error called , “Function expressions not named” when I use the map method